# Filezilla cannot upload file on ftp on Ubuntu: 533 transfer failed

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, ftp, laravel

I have Laravel project on Ubuntu. Project is placed in `/var/www/html/myproj`.
I have my local project on Windows and after some changes I want to upload MyController.php on Ubuntu.
From Filezilla I get message: `File couldn't be transferred`
On Ubuntu file is in:

```
user1@bpl:/var/www/html/myproj/app/Http/Controllers/Admin$ ls -al
total 76
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 13 12:26 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 www-data www-data  4096 Mar 14 21:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data  1170 Mar 13 12:26 AuthController.php
```

For uploading I user `ftpuser1`, this user is added to www-data group:

```
user1@bpl:/var/www/html/myproj$ getent group www-data
www-data:x:33:user1,ftpuser1
```

Home directory of `ftpuser1` is:

```
user1@bpl:/var/www/html/myproj$ eval echo ~ftpuser1
/var/www/html/
```

---

vsftpd works, there is no problem with ftp deamon, because generally I can upload files via `Filezilla`, I have problem with upload files into `Laravel` project into `Admin` directory

```
user1@bpl:/var/www/html/myproj$ systemctl status vsftpd
● vsftpd.service - vsftpd FTP server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vsftpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-03-11 18:23:37 UTC; 3 days ago
 Main PID: 1073 (vsftpd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/vsftpd.service
           └─1073 /usr/sbin/vsftpd /etc/vsftpd.conf
```

---

This is response in Filezilla from server:

```
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (185,163,47,161,39,70).
Command:    STOR AuthController.php
Response:   553 Could not create file.
Error:  Critical file transfer error
Status: Retrieving directory listing of "/myproj/app/Http/Controllers/Admin"...
```

---

On this website, I've found article who permissions for Laravel files should be set: [Laravel files on Ubuntu permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

and it is described that for file permission should be 644 the same as I have:

> Then you set all your directories to 755 and your files to 644... SET
> file permissions
>
> ```
> sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
> ```
>
> SET directory permissions
>
> ```
> sudo find /path/to/your/laravel/root/directory -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
> ```

but this configuration don't allow upload files using Filezilla and vsftpd

Comment: What ftp daemon do you use on Ubuntu? Or do you want to use sftp? Is vsftpd up and running on your Ubunu? Please run 'systemctl status vsftpd' and post output here.

Comment: @ThomasAichinger  I added response in question

Comment: Ok, then it is a file permission problem. Where (full path) do you want to store the file? What owner and what permission does this directory have?

Comment: I uploading files into /var/www/myproject directory, I think that permissions shold be chmod 664 not 644, when I changed on 664 I can upload without problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the permissions of upload dir

```
chmod 664 /var/www/myproject
```

Answer (score 0):

I checked and found my recursive directory of ftp home directory was with root owner, So just changed the permission.

```
$sudo chown -R ftp1:ftp1 /home/ftp1
$sudo chmod -R 777 /home/ftp1
```